# How to install multiple TRAC versions on Windows

Tags: windows, trac, multiple-versions

We have been using TRAC 0.11.1 for quite some time now and have a lot of projects running with it. Now we are facing a migration to a new server and would like to start using TRAC 0.12.2.

Of course migrating all 0.11.1 projects to 0.12.2 would be possible, but would also be a lot of work while a lot of them only remain for reference. For new projects, we would like to benefit from the new functionality in 0.12.2.

So, we would like to combine a 0.11 installation to maintain the existing projects and start using 0.12 for the new projects. We run Python 2.6.6 on Windows with mod_wsgi in Apache. We have studied a solution on the [TRAC website](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleVersions), but it is for Linux. Also information on the mod_wsgi wiki (http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithTrac) seems to work only on Linux, as it uses a daemon mode which is not available on Windows.

Anybody has suggestions how to use both TRAC 0.11 and 0.12 on the same Python installation on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

- install both versions of Trac outside of the Python environment (like `c:\trac\11` and `c:\trac\12`)
- define separate virtual hosts for each group of projects
- in each virtual host at the beginning of each `.wsgi` alter the path like:

.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'c:/trac/11')
# sys.path.insert(0, 'c:/trac/12')
```

I'm currently using this method for Django (on Apache + mod_wsgi)

Comment: You can't do this if using subversion support in Trac. This is because the Python wrappers for subversion don't usually work in a sub interpreter meaning you need to force the use of the main interpreter and you wouldn't be able to do that for two different Trac instances where they are wanting to use two different versions of Trac software.

Comment: @Graham: can you elaborate a little bit more about that? I'm not using subversion these days, and I'm just altering sys.path, so I can't see wright now what could be the problem.

Comment: Per 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithTrac', if using Python wrappers for subversion, you must force use of main interpreter by setting 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}'. You can though only run the one version of Trac at same time in same interpreter and since Windows doesn't have mod_wsgi daemon mode, you cant therefore have Trac's run in separate processes. You are therefore restricted on Windows to running just one version of Trac if also using Python wrappers for subversion.

Comment: @Graham: in this case I think two separate `Apache + mod_wsgi` instances with separate `sys.path` for Python should work. I will try and test it later today.

Comment: Currently testing an installation of two Python versions, each for a TRAC instance. Use mod_WSGI for one and mod_Pyton for the other. This allows me to run two TRAC versions alongside and that works. I still have an issue getting Subversion-Python bindings for both versions though...

Comment: @Hoppie I think that `mod_Python` is deprecated, did you tried two separate `Apache + mod_wsgi` instances, each using a separate instance of Python and svn bindings?